# How do I get the value '100.000,00' as a variable in the description array below?

Tags: php

How do I get the value '100.000,00' as a PHP variable in the array named description below

````
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2021-08-09
            [description] => Array
                (
                    [0] => PENAMBAHAN SALDO
                    [1] => 0976JHOI4096
                    [2] => 0000
                    [3] => 100,000.00
                )

            [jenis] => TAMBAH
        )
)```
````

Comment: echo $variable[0]['description'][3];

Comment: @RakeshkumarOad you should make that an answer and get credit for being the correct one :-) (perhaps adding a bit more context)

Answer (score 1):

try this you will get your result .

```
echo $variable[0]['description'][3];
```

Comment: How about i have more than 1 array

Comment: you mean in loop ?

Comment: Yeah, the array always on the last index of description